# Create a tableview, based on indexPathsForSelectedRows

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have two TableView ViewControllers - A and B.
In  "TableViewController A"  each row of a table is a name, taken from a names array:

```
var names = ["Alex", "Helen", "Kate", "Margo", "Mike", "Tom"]
```

In  "TableViewController A" I can choose several items from a list. As a result I get an `indexPathsForSelectedRows`. Lets say, I have chosen Alex and Kate - so `indexPathsForSelectedRows` will be `[[0,0], [0, 2]]`. After this indexPathsForSelectedRows via segue is send to  "TableViewController B".

**The question is: What should be written in cellForRowAt method of  "TableViewController B" so it shows only those items, that has been selected in "TableViewController A"?**

I understand, that somehow have to teach a table in "TableViewController B" that its first cell should take `0` object from `names` array and second cell should take object `#2`. But up to now I'm failing to figure out a proper code for this.

Comment: `names[selected[row].row]`

Comment: Give TableViewControllerB `names`  filtered by only the selected rows. So it will have only the previously selected ones, so its create it "data source" with that instead of having the whole `var names = ["Alex", "Helen", "Kate", "Margo", "Mike", "Tom"] `.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a dictionary of selected IndexPaths. Use **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** and **didDeselectRowAtIndexPath** to add and remove key/value pairs to the dictionary.
2. Pass this dictionary to ViewController B
3. Display names in table of ViewController B based on comparison of dictionary index

Hope it helps!
Happy Coding....